# amgpu-dkms package kernel module build error

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, amd

`uname -a` : `Linux me 5.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.1-1 (2020-10-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When upgrading the amdgpu-dkms package it runs into an error in the kernel building phase. Both `config.log` and `make.log` complain of a missing `autoconf.h`. `make.log` suggests `Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.` That complains of a missing `mkmakefile`. Could this be an issue with my linux headers installation or something else? How can I obtain or create the missing config files?

Output of `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.5.24-1109583) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.5.24-1109583 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.5.24-1109583
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.5.24-1109583 DKMS files...
Building for 5.9.0-1-amd64
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 5.9.0-1-amd64
configure: error: in `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/amd/dkms':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.9.0-1-amd64 (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.5.24-1109583); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu (= 20.30-1109583); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu (= 20.30-1109583) | amdgpu-hwe (= 20.30-1109583); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-hwe is not installed.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 20.30-1109583) | amdgpu-pro-hwe (= 20.30-1109583); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-pro-hwe is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Content of `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/amd/dkms/config.log`:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by amdgpu-dkms configure 19.40, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = windexDebiant
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.9.0-1-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 5.9.1-1 (2020-10-17)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/lib/dkms


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1881: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1949: result: /bin/install -c
configure:2008: checking for gcc
configure:2024: found /bin/gcc
configure:2035: result: gcc
configure:2264: checking for C compiler version
configure:2273: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Debian 10.2.0-15) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2284: $? = 0
configure:2273: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.0-15' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-mPxEea/gcc-10-10.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-mPxEea/gcc-10-10.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (Debian 10.2.0-15) 
... rest of stderr output deleted ...
configure:2284: $? = 0
configure:2273: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2284: $? = 1
configure:2273: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2284: $? = 1
configure:2304: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2326: gcc  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/arch/x86/include   -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/arch/x86/include/generated   -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include     -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/include  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/uapi    -include /lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/linux/kconfig.h  conftest.c  >&5
In file included from <command-line>:32:
/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/linux/kconfig.h:7:10: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <generated/autoconf.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:2330: $? = 1
configure:2368: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "amdgpu-dkms"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "amdgpu-dkms"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "19.40"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "amdgpu-dkms 19.40"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2373: error: in `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/amd/dkms':
configure:2375: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/arch/x86/include  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/arch/x86/include/generated   -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include     -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/include  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/uapi    -include /lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/linux/kconfig.h'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/arch/x86/include  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/arch/x86/include/generated   -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include     -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/build/include  -I/lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/uapi    -include /lib/modules/5.9.0-1-amd64/source/include/linux/kconfig.h'
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
KERNEL_MAKE=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LINUX=''
LINUX_OBJ=''
LINUX_SYMBOLS=''
LINUX_VERSION=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='amdgpu-dkms'
PACKAGE_STRING='amdgpu-dkms 19.40'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='amdgpu-dkms'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='19.40'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "amdgpu-dkms"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "amdgpu-dkms"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "19.40"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "amdgpu-dkms 19.40"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Content of `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/make.log`

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-5.6.5.24-1109583 for kernel 5.9.0-1-amd64 (amd64)
Sat 24 Oct 2020 08:30:59 PM EDT
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-amd64'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-common/Makefile:718: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-amd64'
```

Output of `sudo make oldconfig && make prepare`:

```
sh: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-common/scripts/mkmakefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-common/Makefile:552: outputmakefile] Error 127
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-1-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
```